# loop read the sheets and add the sheets as another column in R

Tags: r

So I have multiple sheets in one excel file (e.g.tabs of sheets: s1, s2, s3) . 
I want to create a function to read them in and attach each tab of sheets another column with their repetitious tabname, and then combine them together as a data frame.

#####Step1 read in multiple tabs of sheets in a function

```
s1<-data.frame(ID=c(132,453,644)) 
s2<-data.frame(ID=c(1332,4532,6443)) 
s3<-data.frame(ID=c(432,643,747))

> s1
   ID
1 132
2 453
3 644
> s2
    ID
1 1332
2 4532
3 6443
> s3
   ID
1 432
2 643
3 747
```

######Result Step 2

```
s1$tabname<-c(rep('s1',nrow(s1)))
> s1
   ID tabname
1 132      s1
2 453      s1
3 644      s1
s2$tabname<-c(rep('s2',nrow(s2)))
> s2
    ID tabname
1 1332      s2
2 4532      s2
3 6443      s2
s3$tabname<-c(rep('s3',nrow(s3)))
> s3
   ID tabname
1 432      s3
2 643      s3
3 747      s3
```

####My ultimate goal

```
ultimate<-rbind(s1,s2,s3)
> ultimate
    ID tabname
1  132      s1
2  453      s1
3  644      s1
4 1332      s2
5 4532      s2
6 6443      s2
7  432      s3
8  643      s3
9  747      s3
```

####I'm stuck with step 2 to add the col according to their tab names and had to hard code step 3 as well. My codes are as below, can someone provide me any hint?

#

```
library("readxl")
Import<-function(Ref){

  Excel.Ref<-read_xlsx("The Excel Sheet I Have.xlsx", sheet = Ref)

  for (Ref in 1:length(Ref)){
    Excel.Ref<-cbind(Excel.Ref, 

                     Excel.Tab<- data.frame (Tab_name =rep(Ref,nrow(Excel.Ref))))
  }
  return(Excel.Ref)
  print(Ref)
}
d<-c('s1','s2','s3')

Obs<-apply(d<-as.matrix(d), 1, function(x)do.call(Import, as.list(x)))
```

Comment: This looks like it would be easier to do using `purrr`: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed your desired result using a combination of readxl and tidyverse. I created a file on my environment called test_file with the sheets.

```
##First: get all sheet names
sheets_to_read <- readxl::excel_sheets("test_file.xlsx")

##Second: read all sheets, add tabname, and then bind rows
x <- bind_rows(lapply(1:length(sheets_to_read),
            function(i)readxl::read_excel("test_file.xlsx",
                       sheet = sheets_to_read[i]) %>%
                       mutate(tabname = sheets_to_read[i])))

x
```

Comment: Thanks Harro, this works really well! I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: Great. Would you mind upvoting or/and accepting the answer.

Comment: Hey Cyranka,  is there any possible I can convert each column of the sheets from numeric to character in the function? I'm encountering such issue that unable to combine them due to fail to convert numeric to character format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `dplyr` solution:

```
Import <- function(xlsxfile,col_names){
  # get names of sheets in input xlsxfile
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(xlsxfile)
  # sheets as list
  l <- lapply(sheets, readxl::read_xlsx, path=xlsxfile, col_names=col_names)
  # sheets as data.frame
  dplyr::bind_rows(l,.id="tabname")  
}

Import(xlsxfile,col_names="ID")

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  tabname    ID
  <chr>   <dbl>
 2 1       132  
 3 1       453  
 4 1       644  
 6 2       1332 
 7 2       4532 
 8 2       6443  
10 3       432  
11 3       643  
12 3       747
```

Use `col_names` argument of `read_xlsx()` to specify the name of the column with tabs' names.

Use `bind_rows()` for binding a list of `data.frames` into a single `data.frame`, keeping track of the originating`data.frame` in the new column whose name is given by `.id` argument.